# Find same text and add class to container with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, match, case-sensitive

I’m trying to find if any of `h2` texts matches with `h1` text. Plus not being case sensitive. If finds a match, then add class for the container `Product-div`.

```
<div id="PageHeader">
  <h1>Same text</h1>
</div>

<div class="Product">
  <h2 class="ProductName">Product name 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="Product">
  <h2 class="ProductName">Same text</h2>
</div>

<div class="Product">
  <h2 class="ProductName">Product name 2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: How meny h1 tags you have? only one?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Do you want exact match of the text or part of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below. Read `h1` text and make it to lowecase ( as you said text compare is not case sensitive). Iterate all `h2` and compare its text with `h1`, if matches then add class to its parent `div`.

```
$(function(){
  var h1Text = $('#PageHeader h1').text().toLowerCase();
    $('.Product .ProductName').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toLowerCase()==h1Text)
           $(this).closest('.Product').addClass('containerProd');
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/psj4m00p/35/)

Comment: This seems to being exactly what I was looking. Yes, exact match and not case sensitive. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question. I found couple cases where there maybe extra spaces before and after text. And exact match doesn't work anymore... `<h2 class="ProductName">  Same text </h2>` Any idea?

Comment: in that case use `.trim()` like `$('#PageHeader h1').text().toLowerCase().trim();`, this will remove after / before text. use this while reading text from `h2` also like `$(this).text().toLowerCase().trim()==h1Text`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var text=$("#PageHeader h1").text();

$('.ProductName:contains("'+ text +'")').parent().addClass('Product-div');
```

I believe the code is self-explained by functions

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czpnafzx/1/)

For case-sensitive add this query which converts function `contains()` to case-sensitive:

```
//Contains to case-sensitive
Query.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
};

var text = $("#PageHeader h1").text();

$('.ProductName:Contains("' + text + '")').parent().addClass('Product-div');
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/czpnafzx/4/)

Comment: I think this will fail for 'not case sensitive' and 'exact text' matching, see this http://jsfiddle.net/czpnafzx/2/

Comment: Yep, 'exact text' match is needed. This works great too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var h1Text = $("h1").text();
$.each($("h2"),function(key,val){
  if( $(val).text().toLowerCase() == h1Text.toLowerCase() )
  {
      $($(this).parent()[0]).addClass("Product-div");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var header=$('#PageHeader h1').text();
$('.Product ProductName').each(function() {
  if( $( this ).text()==header)
  {
     $( this ).parent('.product').addClass( "your class" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = $("#PageHeader h1").text();
$('.Product h2').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase();
}).parent().addClass('Product-div');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04x2j3q1/)**